# All the books from the cart of my ecommerce site is not getting inserted into database table.

Tags: php, mysql, database, e-commerce

I am building the ecommerce site. I am having the problem in my cart. If 1 customer is buying 2 books from my ecommerce site then only 1 book is getting inserted into my table. Also, duplicate values is getting inserted. Please fix this.

//cart.php

```
<?php include_once("header.php");?>
<div id="products_box">
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <table align="center" width="700" bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
 <br>
 <tr align="center">
  <td style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px" colspan="4"><h2> Your Book(s) Details </h2></td>
 </tr>

 <tr align="center" style="font-size:20px; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'">
 <th>Remove</th>
 <th>Book(s)</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>
 <th>Total Price</th>
 </tr>

 <?php
 $total=0;
 global $con;
 $ip = getIp();
 $sel_price = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";
 $run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  while($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price))
 {
  $b_id = $p_price['cb_id'];
  $b_price = "select * from books where b_id='$b_id'";
  $run_book_price = mysqli_query($con, $b_price) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  while($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_book_price))
  {
   $b_price = array($pp_price['b_price']);
   $b_title = $pp_price['b_title'];
   $b_image = $pp_price['b_image'];
   $single_price = $pp_price['b_price'];

   $values = array_sum($b_price);
   $total += $values;

   if(isset($_POST['update_qty']))
 { 
  if(isset($_POST['qty' . $b_id]))
   {


    $qty = (int)$_POST['qty' . $b_id];
    $run_update = "update cart set qty='$qty' where cb_id='$b_id'";
    $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $run_update) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $total = $total*$qty;

  }
 }

 ?>

 <tr align="center"> 
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]"  value="<?php echo $b_id; ?>"/> </td>
 <td><h3><?php echo $b_title; ?></h3>
 <img src="admin_area/books_images/<?php echo $b_image; ?>" width="100" height="100"  style="border: ridge"/>
 </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="qty<?php echo($b_id); ?>"  size="8" value="
  <?php
  $default_qty=1;
  if(!isset($_POST['qty']))
  {
   echo $default_qty;
  }
  ?>"/></td>

 <td> <?php echo "Rs.\n". $single_price; ?></td>
 </tr>

 <?php  } }?>

 <tr align="right">
   <td colspan="4"><b> Sub Total: </b></td>
   <td colspan="4"><?php echo "Rs.\n". $total; ?></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
  <td align="left" style="padding-left:12px"><input type="submit" name="remove_pro" value="Remove" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF"/></td>


  <td align="center" style="padding-right:20px"><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF" /></td>


   <td align="center" style="padding-left:12px"><input type="submit" name="update_qty" value="Update Quantity" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF"/></td>


  <td align="right" colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout" style="background: #000000; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF; margin-right:10px"/></td>
  </tr>

 </table>

 </form>


 <?php

  global $con;
  $ip = getIp();

  if(isset($_POST['remove_pro']))
 {
  foreach($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id)
 {
  $delete_pro = "delete from cart where cb_id='$remove_id' AND ip_add='$ip'";
  $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $delete_pro) or die(mysqli_error($con));
  if($run_query)
  {
   echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
  }
 }
}

 if(isset($_POST['continue']))
{
 echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
}

 if(isset($_POST['checkout']))
{
 echo "<script>window.open('checkout.php','_self')</script>";
}


 ?>

</div>


</div>



</div>
<!--Content Wrapper Ends--->


<?php include_once("footer.php");?>
<!--Main Wrapper Ends-->


</body>

</html>
```

//cod.php  //Cash on Delivery page

```
<?php include_once("header.php");?>

<div id="products_box">
<br>
 <h2 style="color:#CD5C5C; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:35px; padding-right:80px;"> Your Order Details are: </h2><br>

 <form method="get" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <?php
 $total=0;
 global $con;
 $ip = getIp();
 $sel_price = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";
 $run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  while($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price))
 {
  $b_id = $p_price['cb_id'];
  $b_price = "select * from books where b_id='$b_id'";
  $run_book_price = mysqli_query($con, $b_price) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  $b_id2 = $p_price['cb_id'];
  $b_qty = "select * from cart where cb_id='$b_id2'";
  $run_qty2 = mysqli_query($con, $b_qty) or die(mysqli_error($con));


  $b_ip = $p_price['ip_add'];
  $b_qty = "select * from customers where customer_ip='$b_ip'";
  $run_qty3 = mysqli_query($con, $b_qty) or die(mysqli_error($con));

  $i=0;
  while($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_book_price))
  {
   $b_price = array($pp_price['b_price']);
   $b_id = $pp_price['b_id'];
   $b_title = $pp_price['b_title'];
   $b_image = $pp_price['b_image'];
   $b_deliverychar = $pp_price['b_deliverychar'];
   $single_price = $pp_price['b_price'];

   $values = array_sum($b_price);
   $total += $values;

   while($bb_qty = mysqli_fetch_array($run_qty2))
  {
   $b_qty = $bb_qty['qty'];

   while($bb_cust = mysqli_fetch_array($run_qty3))
  {
   $c_name = $bb_cust['customer_name'];
   $c_address = $bb_cust['customer_address'];
   $c_city = $bb_cust['customer_city'];
   $c_state = $bb_cust['customer_state'];


   if(isset($_POST['update_qty']))
 { 
  if(isset($_POST['qty' . $b_id]))
   {
    $qty = (int)$_POST['qty' . $b_id];
    $run_update = "update cart set qty='$qty' where cb_id='$b_id'";
    $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $run_update) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $total = $total*$qty;
   }
 }

 ?>

 <h3 style="font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro'; color: #0000FF; text-align:left; font-size:23px; padding-left:-8px; padding-top:90px;"><?php echo $b_id; ?>&nbsp;)&nbsp; Title:&nbsp;<?php echo $b_title; ?></h3>

 <img src="admin_area/books_images/<?php echo $b_image; ?>" width="200" height="200"  style="border: ridge" align="left"/>

 <h3 style="font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro'; color:#0000FF; font-size:23px; padding-right:420px; padding-top:30px;"><?php if($b_qty==0)
 {
  echo "Quantity: 1";
 }
  else
  {
   echo "Quantity:\n" . $b_qty;
  } ?><h3/>
 <h3 style="font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro'; color:#0000FF; font-size:23px; padding-right:290px; padding-top:10px;"><?php echo "Delivery Charges: Rs.\n"  . $b_deliverychar; ?><h3/>

 <h3 style="font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro'; color: #FF0000; font-size:30px; padding-right:440px; padding-top:40px;"><?php echo "Rs.\n". $single_price; ?></h3>

 <?php  } } } }?>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br /> 

    <div class="info">
   <h3 style="font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro'; color:#006633; text-align:center; font-size:26px; padding-right:90px;">   <?php echo "Name: \n" . $c_name; ?></h3><br />

  <h3 style="font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro'; color:#006633; text-align:left; font-size:22px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:10px;"> 
  <?php echo "Address:\n" . $c_address;  ?></h3>


  <h3 style="font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro'; color:#006633; text-align:left; font-size:22px; padding-bottom:30px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:10px;"> 
   <?php echo "City:\n" . $c_city; ?></h3>

    <h3 style="font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro'; color:#006633; text-align:left; font-size:22px; padding-bottom:30px; padding-left:10px;"> 
   <?php echo "State:\n" . $c_state; ?></h3>
 </div>


  <div class="subtotal">
 <b style="font-family:'Adobe Caslon Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro'; color: #FF0000; font-size:30px;">Total:
   <?php echo "Rs.\n". $total; ?> </b>
   </div>

  <div class="confirm">
  <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Place Order" style="background: #0000FF; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold', 'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Adobe Caslon Pro'; font-size:25px; color:#FFFFFF; cursor:pointer" /></td>
  </div>
  </div>
   </form>

 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['confirm']))
{
 $confirm=$_GET['confirm'];

 $insert = "insert into cod (cust_name, book_name, price, total_price, image, date, delivery_char, qty, address, city, state) values ('$c_name', '$b_title', '$single_price', '$total', '$b_image', now(), '$b_deliverychar', '$b_qty', '$c_address', '$c_city', '$c_state')";

 $insert_con = mysqli_query($con, $insert) or die(mysqli_error($con));

 if($insert_con)
 {
  echo "<script>alert('Order Placed Successfully')</script>"; 
  echo "<script>window.open('confirm_order.php','_self')</script>";
  exit();
 }
}
```

//confirm_order.php  //Confirmation of Order page

```
<?php include_once("header.php");?>
<div id="products_box">
<?php

 $get_cod="select * from cod";
 $run_cod=mysqli_query($con, $get_cod) or die(mysqli_error($con));

 while($row_cod=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cod))
{
 $cod_id=$row_cod['cod_id'];
 $cust_name=$row_cod['cust_name'];
 $book_name=$row_cod['book_name'];
 $price=$row_cod['price'];
 $total_price=$row_cod['total_price'];
 $image=$row_cod['image'];
 $date=$row_cod['date'];
 $delivery_char=$row_cod['delivery_char'];
 $qty=$row_cod['qty'];
 $address=$row_cod['address'];
 $city=$row_cod['city'];
 $state=$row_cod['state'];

 echo "
        <div id='single_product'>

        <h3>Customer Name: \n $cust_name</h3>
        <h3> Book: \n $book_name</h3>
        <h3> Price: \n Rs. $price</h3>
        <img src='admin_area/books_images/$image' width='200' height='200' />
        <h3> Total Price: Rs. \n $price</h3>
        <h3>  Order Placed on: \n $date</h3>
        <h3>  Delivery Charges:\n $delivery_char</h3>
        <h3>  Quantity:\n $qty</h3>
        <h3> Address:\n $address</h3>
        <h3>  City:\n $city</h3>
        <h3> State:\n $state</h3>      



      </div>





 ";

}
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php include_once("footer.php");?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$total = $total*$qty;
```

to

```
$total += $total*$qty;
```